# Ubuntu Unity: how do I change desktop color schemes so color(titleBar) != color(menuBar)?

Tags: ubuntu, window, styles

What's the Unity equivalent to Windows' [ Control Panel > Personalization > 
Window Color and Appearance ]?

The problem is that the title bar and the menu bar both have brown backgrounds.
The menu bar is a shade darker, but not enough that I keep grabbing it to move
the window.

Comment: Third-party tool for Unity tweaking: [UnSettings](http://www.florian-diesch.de/software/unsettings/).

Comment: Nothing applicable in the gconf editor?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at other GTK themes, icons themes or window borders. There is a theme called 'Adwaita' available in the Canonical PPAs which might help you. To install it, write "`sudo apt-get install gnome-themes`" (not sure of the package name) in a terminal. Otherwise you can search other themes on the Internet. You can find some themes on [Gnome Art](http://art.gnome.org) or on [WebUpd8](http://www.webupd8.org/).

You can also use Ubuntu tweaking tools ([Ubuntu Tweak](http://ubuntu-tweak.com), [MyUnity](http://www.uielinux.org/myunity/), [Gnome Tweak Tool](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gnome-tweak-tool/) and the newcomer [Unsettings](http://www.florian-diesch.de/software/unsettings/)) to customize your theme (Icons, Window Border, Theme...). Perhaps there are combinations which respond to your needs, who knows ?

**EDIT for Tweaking tools** : there is also the `com.canonical.unity-greeter` entry in the dconf editor (and the dconf editor in general).